# Cutting an apple in a blink of an eye

Tags: internal-consistency

Lets say you are John and a Master of using samurai sword, there is an apple in front of you and you slowly put your body to a stance while slowly pulling your sword from its container as soon as the small part of your blade is visible you immediately return the sword completely to its container by that time the apple is already sliced.

Being that said your disciple came to you and asked;

- Is it even possible for a human body?
- If possible, how much it will cost for me to achieve this skill?

Comment: Welcome Keith. It's recommended that newcomers familiarize them-selves with the help center, particularly that part which explains [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions and  [ask] them.

Comment: Why not, while the master is slowly pulling out the katana from it's sheath the hidden latch released a blade from the concealed compartment within the sheath directed to the position of the apple... Notice that the end of the sheath is alway aimed at the target also it cost 2500yen on ebay.

Comment: "_It'll cost you nothing. I'll pay you ten bucks an hour to replace my idiot assistant who can't even set up a simple apple-slicing trick without it falling apart as soon as I look at the damn thing_".

Comment: @StarfishPrime: so the apple is already sliced horizontally might as well peel and stick the skin back on ;D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, it's possible

The apples was pre-sliced before John even started drawing the sword. Nowhere in the premise it says it was whole.

## The imperceptible slicing is impossible

If you actually wanted John to pull the sword out, slice the apple, then put the sword back to the *same* position it was in just before the swing, without anybody being able to see the motion even when looking at him, then that's not possible in the real world.

Various studies have been done on what's the smallest time-range a human can detect something. With various parameters such as "a word" and "reading it" or "a picture" and "comprehending it". And even for those, the time to *recognise* what something could be as low as 100ms or less. Simply *detecting* something needs less time. And movement is even easier to detect since it's just just still image flashed in a moment.

If the apple *wasn't* pre-sliced and an observer wasn't able to detect any motion, then the only logical conclusion is that John cheated. Maybe he distracted the observer for a moment or had a ghost slice the apple. John didn't just go past the speed of human perception.

Comment: agreed the object or blade must move at 17500 meters per second to become invisible to the untrained eye, on top of that the blade must be sheathed after the execution which "It's like jumping from a moving car, off a bridge and into a shot glass." only this time the jumper is an africking elephant!

Comment: A must add that while we would see John draw his sword, swing and undraw, we might not see actual slice of an apple. Mostly because we are destructed from apple by more dangerous to us sword swinging. It's like "street magic".

Comment: @user6760 that's actually not entirely true. It would heavily depend on several factors - the calculation there assumes a wide viewing angle and quite a lot of distance covered (70 metres) and *quite* perfect conditions. It's coming from [here](https://www.visiondirect.co.uk/blog/how-fast-can-we-see) and it's not actually realistic. With that said, you still have to move literally inhumanly fast which is impossible. As the term "inhumanly" already suggests.

Comment: @ksbes I've taken that into account. I did some back of the envelope calculations of *just* the tip of the sword moving back and forth to slice an apple. The results weren't promising. You would need John to be able to move the tip of the sword at *at least* 5 m/s and likely a lot more. That depends several factors I made assumptions on but still  - 5 m/s is still 18 km/h which is easy to detect by a human. [The fastest punch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Liddell) is about 72 km/h and is still *perceptible*. So, John has to move the blade at inhuman speed.

Comment: @VLAZ, if you were right no focus would be possible. Human can't notice more then one "fast movement" at a time. So if we are watching apple and only apple we would see the slice. But if we are watching John and his hands, we would miss the actual slicing, because the apple is out of our attention.

Comment: @ksbes but if you watch John, you'd *notice* at least some movement, even if you don't see the apple being sliced. And if you watch the apple, you'd still see *some* movement, even if you don't notice *exactly* what John does. This also depends on where the observer is located, though at the right distance and right angle, and they can watch both John and the apple. Still, I don't see a possibility that an observer will complete be completely unable to see anything from the slicing motion other than the after effects (the apple being sliced).

Comment: @user6760 I read 17500m/s and imagined John turning into red mist from the shockwave of the blade moving at Mach 51. That sure would be a skill.

Comment: @AmiralPatate the apple will also not be "sliced" as much as "vaporised". And yes, at this speed an observer will not be able to *see* the movement but I think they will be able to perceive it. First by the sonic boom that might leave their eardrums destroyed and then by being tossed around. Although at the right distance the movement *could* be imperceptible...since the observer will just die and thus be unable to perceive anything.

Comment: I'm getting flash backs to those videos where you watch some guys shooting basketballs and you don't even notice the gorilla wandering about until it's pointed out

Answer (score 6):

As the other answer pointed out, it's pretty much impossible for an attentive observer. If the oberserver isn't quite paying attention, how close can we get?

Here is a video of some youtuber in his backyard dropping an apple and then slicing it by drawing the Katana with the same hand. https://youtu.be/KezyWQIMh3Q?t=6

The apple drops about 30cm before it's sliced. This works out as around a quarter of a second. That's very much perceptible to somebody with their eyes open, but it's less than a slow blink. A trained street magician can easily time their tricks to coincide with blinks, or even [induce the subject to blink at particular times](https://peerj.com/articles/1873/). With a little active misdirection, the slice could be hidden from view. Most likely, a master swordsman would be trained to recognize when their opponent's attention wanes briefly, so this is a natural skill for them to have.

The bigger problem is sheathing the sword again. Doing that increases the time to at least half a second, which is a much longer blink, and is a lot more difficult than the reverse. There's also a very serious risk of stabbing the sword into your hand or thigh if you get it wrong.

The easiest way to achieve this would be to not draw the sword entirely, so the sheathing is simply the reverse of of drawing. If you only draw half the blade, we're back to a draw time of 0.25s. This doesn't work for an apple sat in front of you on a table, but one thrown into the air in front of you might just work. This would then make it difficult to time it with the blink, but again, with a little misdirection, it might be done.

Comment: "*The bigger problem is sheathing the sword again.*" no requirement for the sword to be sheathed imperceptibly. What an observer has to see is John unsheathing the sword then sheathing it. So, anime-like move. John, however, *can* use misdirection. A blink or a saccade (the time when your eye moves and your brain essentially turns it off) can last *up to* about 150ms. Which gives a lot more leeway for John to act than an unblinking focused stare but still.

Comment: It would also work under stroboscopic lighting, at 4 strobes or less per second.